# Getting Resource Not Found Error While using Azure face api

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cognitive-services

[image]in Below image i have mentioned api key and uri

[image]

Configuration for face api in azure portal

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I observed :

1. Location that you use is WestCentralUs but the resource location is in CentralUS
2. You are using the GET method whereas the method that is supported is **PUT**

**Reference:**

You could use the below link to check on the usage:
https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Your `FaceServiceClient` should use the base URL of your Face API resource, that is to say your "endpoint" value (the one partially hidden). Or the generic URL of Face API for the region of your resource, so "https://centralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/",
- You should use the latest Face SDK for dotnet: there is no `FaceServiceClient` in it, it is a `FaceClient` (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.faceclient?view=azure-dotnet&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)). The official SDK is this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face/2.7.0-preview.1 . If you are using "ProjectOxford" packages, it was the previous one, during the preview phase.